# Get JSon data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

can you guys help me, I am not really a JS dev so i am polling my hair out with this one.
i'm working with Ajax to display data from a json file...but it doesn't work, i put console.log almost everywhere to see result but it won't work, here's my code:

encode data:

```
// Inclusion du ficher de fonction permettant de démarrage du contexte de l'applicaiton
Include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."Includes".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."Functions".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."functions.php";

// Initialisation des variables
$action     = '';
$pValue     = '';
$pType      = '';
$pRegion    = '';
$currenthyperviseur = new hyperviseur();
$currentregion      = new region();

// Récupération de l'action passée au webservice
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']!= "")      {$action = $_REQUEST['action']; }
if(isset($_REQUEST['pValue']) && $_REQUEST['pValue']!= "")      {$pValue = base64_decode($_REQUEST['pValue']); }
if(isset($_REQUEST['pType']) && $_REQUEST['pType']!= "")        {$pType = $_REQUEST['pType']; }
if(isset($_REQUEST['pRegion']) && $_REQUEST['pRegion']!= "")    {$pRegion = $_REQUEST['pRegion']; }

// Gestion de l'ensemble des cases du web service
switch($action)
{
    //
    // Permet la récupération de données dans l'Hyperviseur (GET)
    //
    case 'H_getAlmBacPFull'     : echo json_encode($currenthyperviseur->getListAlarmeBac(1));           break;
    case 'H_getAlmBacTFull'     : echo json_encode($currenthyperviseur->getListAlarmeBac(2));           break;
    case 'H_getGrpBacTFull'     : echo json_encode($currenthyperviseur->getListAlarmeQualifBac());      break;

    case 'H_getAlmDetails'      : echo json_encode($currenthyperviseur->getAlarmeDetails($pValue));     break;
    case 'H_getGrpDetails'      : echo json_encode($currenthyperviseur->getGroupeDetails($pValue));     break;

    //
    // Permet la MAJ de données dans l'Hyperviseur (SET)
    //
    case 'H_setCheckAlm'        : echo $currenthyperviseur->setAlarmeCheckAction($pValue);              break;
    case 'H_setGroupAlm'        : echo $currenthyperviseur->setGroupAlarme($pValue);                    break;
    case 'H_setAlmIdGrp'        : echo $currenthyperviseur->setAlarmeIdGrp($pValue);                    break;


    //
    // Permet la récupération de données pour le module 'HyperViseur MoreDetails' (GET)
    //
    case 'HVMD_getContentBloc'  : echo json_encode($currenthyperviseur->getContentBloc($pType, $pValue));   break;


    //
    // Permet la récupération de données pour le module 'Region' (GET)
    //
    case 'R_getListContentBloc' : echo json_encode($currentregion->getListContentBloc($pType));         break;
    case 'R_getContentBloc'     : echo json_encode($currentregion->getContentBloc($pType, $pRegion));   break;
        //
    // Permet la récupération de données pour le module la map des régions
    //
    case 'dashMap_getSite'  : echo json_encode($dashMap_getSite($pRegion);          break;


}
```

function dashMap_getSite($pRegion)  to  get data:

```
    $dataArray = array();
    if($pRegion == 'all')
    {
        $dataLine = array();
        $dataLine['codeSite']   = "01014";
        $dataLine['latitude']   = '46.2625';
        $dataLine['longitude']  = '5.6380';
        $dataLine['nom']        = 'Oyonnax 2';
        $dataLine['nbAlm']      = 10;
        $dataLine['critilevel'] = 2;
        array_push($dataArray, $dataLine);

        $dataLine = array();
        $dataLine['codeSite']   = "04025";
        $dataLine['latitude']   = '44.4242';
        $dataLine['longitude']  = '6.7533';
        $dataLine['nom']        = 'Barcelonette 3 Est TDF';
        $dataLine['nbAlm']      = 0;
        $dataLine['critilevel'] = 1;
        array_push($dataArray, $dataLine);
    }
    return $dataLine;
```

And this second function getArrayOfSiteAjax()  to display it with ajax

```
        console.log(gWsProviderUrl);
        $.ajax({
            url: gWsProviderUrl + '?action=dashMap_getSite&pRegion=all',
            type:  'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
        console.log('arrayOfSite');
                arrayOfSite = data;

                $.each(arrayOfSite, function(currentIdx, currentValue){

                    console.log('codeSite   => ' + currentValue.codeSite );
                    console.log('latitude   => ' + currentValue.latitude );
                    console.log('longitude  => ' + currentValue.longitude );
                    console.log('nom        => ' + currentValue.nom );
                    console.log('nbAlm      => ' + currentValue.nbAlm );
                    console.log('critilevel => ' + currentValue.critilevel);
                });
                console.log('heyy');
            }
        });
```

Thank you !

Comment: You have a `success` callback, what about an `error` callback to see what's wrong? Besides, any error in the console?

Comment: I can't see a JSON file. By "json file", do you mean you create an assoc array in PHP, `json_encode` it and then send it?

Comment: @PeterMader  yes  it's json_encode

Comment: OK, then please share the code where you call `dashMap_getSite` and encode the data to JSON.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: The first snippet looks like PHP. I've added the tag accordingly.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows thank you this is my first time here :)

Comment: @PeterMader i just added the code  where i encode the data to Json.
For the dashMap_getSite i didn't call it anywhere, shoud i ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
case 'dashMap_getSite'  : echo json_encode($dashMap_getSite($pRegion);          break;
```

That's a syntax error and should probably be

```php
case 'dashMap_getSite'  : echo json_encode(dashMap_getSite($pRegion));          break;
```

Because there was an error, the `success` callback didn't get called, an you don't get a message.

To display the data, you could do something like this:

```js
// ...
success: function (data) {
  var container = $('#container'); // the element in which you want to display the data
  // loop over each item in the array
  $.each(data, function (index, element) {
    var outer = $('<div />');
    // element is an object, loop over its properties
    $.each(element, function (key, value) {
      var inner = $('<div />');
      inner.text(key + ': ' + value);
      outer.append(inner);
    })
    container.append(outer);
  });
}
// ...
```

Comment: thank you so much it works...as you said it was a syntax error

Comment: i just have one last question please, if i want to display the data in divs not in the console...what should i have to do ? a SELECT ?